# Email validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this simple regular expression for Emails.

```
/^[a-z]+([\.-_]?[a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z]{3,})+(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$/i;
```

But when I use this example: *first@last@example.com* it's still works, And Also when I remove `@` character from expression :

```
`/^[a-z]+([\.-_]?[a-z0-9]+)*([a-z]{3,})+(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$/i
```

it gives the same result.

This expression allows an infinite number of *at* signs (i.e. `@`) between at least 2 characters in the email !!

Where is the problem with this expression?

Comment: The `[.-_]` matches a lot of chars, incl. `@`. You need `[._-]` instead.

Comment: Good info here on the subject: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: The pattern is rather weird. Why do you use `([a-z]{3,})+`? It seems `[a-z]+` should be enough. Is it `input`? Use `type="email"`

Comment: Your regex rejects many valid email addresses. I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern is rather restrictive, you might think of other options of validating an email address, like `type="email"` if it is an input field validation.

As to why the regex matches `@` even if you take it out, or matches a string with two `@` symbols, that is cased by `[.-_]` that matches a lot of chars as the hyphen creates a  *range* that includes `@`. You need to use `[._-]` instead.

[image]

You may "fix" the regex as

```
/^[a-z]+([._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*[a-z]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$/i
```

However, this regex is not good to use in real life scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that?

```
/^[a-z\.\-_]+@([a-z]{3,})+(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$/
```

Probably with sign `\.-_` you wanted to have either ".", or "-" or "_" to be used inside the regex, but you forgot to escape "minus".

Or you can use your own but with escape:

```
^[a-z]+([\.\-_]?[a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z]{3,})+(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$
```

PS: Remember that a real valid email address could be completely different and has a huge regex, and moreover, each web server defines what is allowed and what is not in email.